# How do I add a space at the beginning of each line

Tags: spacing

I am a beginner with TeX. I am trying to put a few spaces at the beginning of the line. Or a tab, whatever would work. But whatever I try it just puts space on the first line. 
My questions:
How do I add a space in each line
and is there a good cheat sheet for using TeX?

This is a text document and I am trying to add Verilog code to be shown in the final pdf version of the document.
So here is an example of the latex document:

---

```
There are several ways to code a mux. Here is an example below:

\textit{\qquad input wire [7:0]} a;  \\
\textit{\qquad input wire \textit[7:0]} b;  \\
\textit{\qquad input wire [2:0] s;}   \\
\textit{\qquad output wire [7:0] fab;}  

\textit{\qquad assign fab = s[0] ? b : a;}\\  

This code infers an 8bit 2:1 mux.
```

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you really using TeX or LaTeX? Just leave an empty line between two lines (instead of use ``\\``) and this will produce a new paragraph with indentation.

Comment: As Sigur says, leave a blank line to separate paragraphs. In any case, this seems like something that might require special formatting. If you tell us the whole story we might be able to find an even better solution. What are you doing? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I prefer not to have spaces between the lines (though, it does solve the spacing problem).

Comment: I tried adding backquotes//backquotes, at the end of the line but I can see the quotes in the text. I added a gif in my original question above

Comment: @Tialit -- just because there is a blank line between two input lines doesn't mean there will be a vertical space in the output.  that will happen only if the `\parskip` is greater than zero.  if you really don't want the blank lines, then setting up the block with `\hangindent=\parindent` and keeping the ``\\`` should do what you want.

Comment: @barbara - thanks, I'll give it a go

Comment: @barbara I am probably doing something else wrong being new to TEX. I added the \hangindent=\parindent to the header (tried different variations) and brought back the \\ but I still don't get the spaces at the beginning of the line. It looks the same as in my first original gif

Comment: @barbara - it works now. I added \hangindent=0.5in above the paragraph and I get the spacing as needed. A nice trick thank you.

Comment: Grammar question. Is "infers" the word you want, or should it be "implies"?

Comment: The industry convention is to use "Infers". But "implies" is valid too. People will know what you mean.

Comment: Note that `\qquad` in the first line of the paragraph is realized but others `\qquad`s no. The reason is that `\\` is defined as `\hfil\break` and `\qquad` as `\hskip2em`. This `\hskip` is discardable item so it disappear after `\break` (alias `\penalty-10000`).

Comment: @wipet how do I define it better than so it wont be dscarded?

Comment: For example insert empty box: `\hfil\break\null\hskip2em` or `\\\null\qquad`, but this technique is needed very rarely. More common is usage of global parameters `\hangindent` or `\leftskip`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're trying to typeset code, perhaps the [`listings`](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) package will be helpful. You can adjust the left margin using `xleftmargin`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
There are several ways to code a mux. Here is an example below:

\begin{lstlisting}[xleftmargin=1em]
input wire [7:0] a;
input wire [7:0] b;
input wire [2:0] s;
output wire [7:0] fab;
assign fab = s[0] ? b : a;
\end{lstlisting}

This code infers an 8bit 2:1 mux.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To the OP, to make it —possibly— more atractive, use `basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible` in `lstlisting` environment options.

Answer (score 4):

there are several ways to accomplish the indentation of a block of text, where each
line must remain distinct.

an easy approach is to treat each line as a paragraph by leaving a blank line after each
line of the block.  all the lines will be indented uniformly to the usual paragraph
indentation.  disadvantages: it's not easy to control breaks at the end of a page,
and if the page is spaced out because of unbreakable elements, the lines of the "block"
could be spaced out too.

another, not really "latex" way to handle the block is to treat it as a paragraph,
breaking lines explicitly with `\\`, and apply a `\hangindent`, e.g.:

```
\hangindent=\parindent
\textit{\qquad input wire [7:0]} a;  \\
\textit{\qquad input wire \textit[7:0]} b;  \\
\textit{\qquad input wire [2:0] s;}   \\
\textit{\qquad output wire [7:0] fab;}
```

the `\hangindent` persists for just the single paragraph.  the `\parindent` shown can
be replaced by any desired dimension, say `.5in`.  disadvantage: this must be repeated
for every block; although a macro could be applied to make it more compact and allow
the indentation for multiple blocks to be changed uniformly with a single modification
to the macro definition.

**addendum:** egreg suggests a `quote` environment.  just remember that the right-hand
side will be indented by the same amount as the left-hand side.

Comment: Why not a `quote` environment?

Comment: @egreg -- good question.  because i didn't think of it.

Answer (score 2):

How about a `tabular`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
There are several ways to code a mux. Here is an example below:

\begin{tabular}{>{\qquad\itshape\ttfamily\arraybackslash}l}
   input wire [7:0] a;  \\
   input wire \textit[7:0] b;  \\
   input wire [2:0] s;   \\
   output wire [7:0] fab; \\
   assign fab = s[0] ? b : a;
\end{tabular}

This code infers an 8bit 2:1 mux.
\end{document}
```

[image]